# what is the difference between a 'function call' and a 'callback function'?

Tags: function, callback, function-call

**function call**

> Per MDN, A function call is an **expression** that passes control and
>   arguments (if any) to a function and has the form: expression
>   (expression-listopt)

**callback function**

> A callback function is a lucky **function** that gets passed into the enclosing higher-order function: The callback function gets executed (called) inside the higher order function, but not necessarily immediately.
>   https://thenewstack.io/mastering-javascript-callbacks-bind-apply-call/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**function call** is term related to program syntax. it related to generally programs and programming languages. There are no predefined semantic, just term which used to describe programs.

**callback function** is term related to program execution semantic. In some kind  **callback function** is **function call** with scope, which pass as parameter to another function or method, some parameters of callback function can be free variables and callback function executed generally after method or function in which it was passed.